# Find nearby postcode myquery optimization

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I have need find nearby postcode  of point in google map ,
I am using SQL  – Haversine formula.
below is my query

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT Postcode,latitude,longtitude, ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latitude)) *
    COS(RADIANS(longtitude)) * COS(RADIANS($latitude)) * COS(RADIANS($longtitude)) +
    COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(longtitude)) * COS(RADIANS($latitude)) * 
    SIN(RADIANS($longtitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS($latitude))) * 
    3963.1 AS Distance
    FROM postalscheme   
    HAVING Distance <= 4  ");
```

Data is fetched correctly using this query, but my problem is its taking long time to fetch data [3 or 5 min for fetch 20 thousand to 60 thousand data ] .

please help me to optimize this query and work fast .

Comment: how many rows of position data do you have in your database?

Comment: about 20 lacks postcode of UK

Comment: could you already try my solution from below?

Answer (score 0):

you can limit the range of data you have to calculate distances for when you limit the latitude/longitude values to the ones nearby.
(formulas coming from [these slides (page 12ff)](http://de.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL)
This works when you calculate by miles... otherwise you have to adjust the "69" with the right value for kilometers.

```
1° of latitude ~= 69 miles 
1° of longitude ~= cos(latitude)*69
```

When you want to calculate the longitude and latitude for the smaller rectangle, you can use (with your variables above):

```
$dist = 4; // the distance from your query above
$lon1 = $longtitude - $dist / abs(cos(deg2rad($latitude))*69);
$lon2 = $longtitude + $dist / abs(cos(deg2rad($latitude))*69);
$lat1 = $latitude - ($dist / 69);
$lat2 = $latitude + ($dist / 69);
```

and then you modify your query like so:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT Postcode,latitude,longtitude, ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latitude)) *
    COS(RADIANS(longtitude)) * COS(RADIANS($latitude)) * COS(RADIANS($longtitude)) +
    COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(longtitude)) * COS(RADIANS($latitude)) * 
    SIN(RADIANS($longtitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS($latitude))) * 
    3963.1 AS Distance
    FROM postalscheme   
    WHERE longitude BETWEEN $lon1 AND $lon2 
    AND latitude BETWEEN $lat1 AND $lat2
    HAVING Distance <= $dist  ");
```

This should improve the overall speed drastically.